# css logo displaying with margin top on iphone 5 and 6

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress

I am trying to get working my Wordpress site: http://hanacakes.sk and I have som problems with it. I am using `Chrome Developer tools` to test responsive design of my webpage and it's working correctly. But, when my friends tries that page on Iphone 5 they get the following result:
[image: Hanacakes]

and:

[image: Hanacakes]

and when they try it on Iphone 6 they get this:

[image: Hanacakes]

I've also tried the Iphone 5 and 6 simulator online and it looks fine there. Any ideas where could be the problem? I've removed all of the margins top in css but it's still wrong. How would You fix this?

Comment: Please, post some examples of your code and what you tried so far.

Comment: I've only tried to remove all of the margin-top for logo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague` I did exactly this... quick short question...

Answer (score 0):

You have a bizarre zoom effect applied to the logo on hover. I'll bet if you take that off, your problem will go away.

Comment: You mean that on mouse hover effect in css?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I've managed to set the position absolute and the top: -35px and now it's working... anyways thank you @Greg Burkett